# How to prove the triangle is isosceles and determine its area

Tags: analytic-geometry, plane-geometry

Let $P(a,b)$ be a point on the curve $y = \frac{1}{x}$ in first quadrant and let the tangent line at $P$ intersect the $x$-axis at a point $A$. Show that triangle $AOP$ is isosceles and determine its area, where $O$ is the origin.

How do I start to attempt this?

Comment: Have you tried to find the tangent line in terms of $P$ yet?

Comment: Very good. So the slope of $PA$ is $-1/a^2$. Now if you also calculate the slope of $OP$ you should notice something which makes the triangle very symmetric.

Comment: So essentially, the slope of $OP$ is just the inverse of $PA$? @SmileyCraft

Comment: Right, the additive inverse that is. Because $O$ and $A$ lie on the $x$-axis, it follows that $|PA|$=$|OP|$.

Comment: I see now. Thank you so much for your assistance! @SmileyCraft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start approaching the problem, first notice that if P lies on the curve then $P (a, b) = P (a, \frac{1}{a})$.

Secondly, find the slope of the tangent line at $P$, which is precisely $-\frac{1}{a^2}$

Thus equation of the tangent line through $P$ is given by

$$(y - \frac{1}{a}) = (-\frac{1}{a^2})(x-a) \implies a^2y = 2a - x$$

The above line intersects the $x$-axis only at $(2a, 0)$, thus $\ A = (2a, 0)$.

Therefore the coordinates of $\Delta AOP$ are precisely: $$A (2a, 0), \ \ O(0, 0), \ \ P (a, \frac{1}{a})$$
making $AOP$ isosceles. Moreover, the area of $\Delta AOP = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2a \cdot \frac{1}{a} = 1$ unit.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

WLOG $b=1/a>0$

$$xy-1\implies x\dfrac{dy}{dx}+y=0\implies\dfrac{dy}{dx}_{\text{ at }(a,b)}=-\dfrac{1/a}a=-\dfrac1{a^2}$$

The equation of the tangent at $P,$ $$\dfrac{y-1/a}{x-a}=-\dfrac1{a^2}\iff x+a^2y=2a$$

As $x$ axis, $y=0,$ the intersection will be $A(2a,0)$

$$|AP|=?, |OP|=?$$

Answer (score 0):

The tangent line to $y=\frac 1x$ at $P(x_0,y_0)$ is:
$$y=y_0+y'(x_0)(x-x_0)=\frac 1{x_0}-\frac 1{x_0^2}(x-x_0).$$
The point $A(x_1,0)$ has coordinate $x_1$:
$$0=\frac 1{x_0}-\frac 1{x_0^2}(x_1-x_0) \Rightarrow x_1=2x_0,$$
which shows the triangle $PAO$ is isosceles, because the altitude $PB$ is the median too.

Now the area of $\Delta PAO$ is:
$$S=\frac 12 \cdot AO\cdot PB=\frac12 \cdot 2x_0 \cdot \frac1{x_0}=1.$$